# Character higher than "s" cant be encrypted?

Tags: java, encryption

I made simple encryption and decryption methods by following this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8AID7DKhSoM&feature=g-hist
however when its implemented in my program any character higher than "s" is encrypted to a "?"
and then decrypted to a 3. It doesn't seem to happen in the tutorial however even though some of his characters get increased by large numbers. So why does this happen?
Btw here's the relevant part of my program:

```
public class crypt {
public String encrypt(String pass){
        String cryppass_string="";
        int l= pass.length();
        char ch;
        for (int i=0; i<l; i++){
            ch= pass.charAt(i);
            ch+= 12;
            cryppass_string+= ch;
        }
        return cryppass_string;
    }

    public String decrypt (String cryppass_string){
        String pass_string= "";
        int l= cryppass_string.length();
        char ch;
        for (int i=0; i<l; i++){
            ch= cryppass_string.charAt(i);
            ch-= 12;
            pass_string += ch;              
        }
        return pass_string;
    }
}
```

Here's an example :
a password ("astu") needs to be encrypted so its entered, this is done:

```
 char[] newpass= newPassField.getPassword();
        char[] repass= rePassField.getPassword();
        if(Arrays.equals( newpass , repass ))
        {
            if(number==1)
            {

            Login_info.McIntosh_custom_pwd= fileob.string_to_char(cryptob.encrypt(fileob.char_to_string(newpass)));
            fileob.evr_tofile();
            }
```

In another class McIntoshcrypted is declared as:

```
McIntosh_custom_pwd= fileob.string_to_char(cryptob.decrypt(FileData[0]));
```

fileob is an object of class Files

cryptob is an object of class crypt

```
public class Files {

File f= new File("Eng Dept.txt");
public Formatter x;


public void openfile(){ 
try{
    x= new Formatter ("Eng Dept.txt");

}
catch (Exception error){
    System.out.println("error");
}
    }

public void writing(String towrite){
try{    
String filename= "Eng Dept.txt";
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true);
fw.write(towrite);
fw.write(newLine);
fw.close();
    }
catch (Exception eror){
    System.out.println("error");
                        }
}

public String reading_string(int linenum){
    String readline= "";
    String filename= "Eng Dept.txt";
    int lineno;
    try{
        FileReader fr= new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr); 
        for (lineno=1; lineno<= 1000; lineno++){
                if(lineno== linenum){
                    readline= br.readLine();
                                    }
                else 
                    br.readLine();
                                            }
        br.close();
        }
        catch (Exception eror){
            System.out.println("error");    
    }
    return readline;
}

public String char_to_string(char[] toconv){
    int l= toconv.length;
    String converted= "";
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        converted+= toconv[i];
    }
    return converted;
}

public char[] string_to_char(String toconv){
    int l= toconv.length();
    char[] converted = new char[l];
    for (int i= 0; i<l; i++)
    {
        converted[i]=toconv.charAt(i);
    }
    return converted;
}

public void evr_tofile()
{
    f.delete();
    openfile();
    writing(char_to_string(Login_info.McIntosh_custom_pwd));

     }
```

In the txt file "as??" is seen, and the result of

```
System.out.print(Login_info.McIntosh_custom_pwd);
```

is "as33". Hope I explained this correctly...

edit: tried solution

```
public String encrypt(String pass){
        String cryppass_string="";
        int l= pass.length();
        int x=0;
        char ch;
        for (int i=0; i<l; i++){
            ch= pass.charAt(i);
            x= ((ch - 32) + 12) % 126 + 32;
            ch = (char)x;
            cryppass_string+= ch;
        }
        return cryppass_string;
    }

    public String decrypt (String cryppass_string){
        String pass_string= "";
        int l= cryppass_string.length();
        int x=0;
        char ch;
        for (int i=0; i<l; i++){
            ch= cryppass_string.charAt(i);
            x= ch-32;
            ch= (char)x;
            if (ch < 0)
                x= ch+126;
            ch= (char)x;
            x= ch-12+32;
            ch= (char)x;
            pass_string += ch;              
        }
        return pass_string;
    }
```

Comment: As expected, `System.out.println(decrypt(encrypt("astu")));` prints `astu`. Can you post a full working example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: i guess that you use some kind of unusual character encoding. could you post your encoding?

Comment: `s` is ASCII 115, so adding 12 to letters over `s` will not be ASCII anymore. Java's internal default encoding is UTF-16, so like assylias said, your problem is not in the part of code you show us. That code works just fine.

Comment: I hope that you're aware that this encryption algorithm can't be qualified as secure. It's OK for a "Disney Magazine puzzle" encryption, but that's all.

Comment: @assylias I tried "astu" and the result I got was "as33". How can I post an example?

Comment: @sketchiii add the code where you encrypt and decrypt "astu" to your question by editing your post (edit link below your question).

Comment: @schippi I googled character encoding and I don't believe I've messed with anything of the sort.

Comment: @sketchii then that is a problem, the default encoding used for input/output depends on your system, the internal encoding is set in stone. Java autoconverts between these encodings and you can loose information in the process. Make sure to pass a sane (Unicode) Charset like "utf-8" whenever you create one of the java.io.* Reader/Writer classes. Also the System.out/System.in streams are stuck with the encoding used by the system console.

Comment: @JB Nizet It was not Disney ( ;-) )who i invented this enryption, it was used long before (Julius Cesar), exactly it is called "Cesarian Cypher". I think most of us have "invented" this cypher in our early programming days ...

Comment: @AlexWien He wasn't saying Disney created it.

Comment: @AHungerArtist I know, therefore the ;-) in parenthesis

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I have the same problem when I try to use encryption. I found [this page](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php) and the class works fine for me. When you change the example keys be careful the the length of your new key is excat the same length of the given excample keys.

Comment: @JackTools.Net If it works for you then your application has serious issues. For starters, a key is not a string. Please don't point to `mcrypt` examples in general (except maybe the one of `mcrypt_encrypt` because the new one was created by me).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you output the values to a text file (web page?) using an operation that converts unprintable characters to `?`, then the decryption problem happens when you read it back in.  If you want to do something like that, you'll need to restrict your encryption to output only printable characters.  One way to do that is to use modular arithmetic to ensure that your encrypted character is within the printable set (ASCII 32 to ASCII 126).  The code you have will transform properly if you read/write binary, but not if you output it as ASCII text.

Encrypt

```
ch = (char)((ch - 32) + 12) % 126 + 32; // extended expression to show rebasing/modulus
```

Decrypt

```
ch = ch - 32;
if (ch < 0) ch = ch + 126;
ch = ch - 12 + 32;
```

Comment: modulo is not bijective so he won't be able to decrypt and he can also decide to use the same charset when writing and reading the file (if that is what he is doing)...

Comment: Or he could write and read it as binary, using a DataOutput/InputStream.

Comment: @assylias - correct the operations aren't duals but as long as he sticks with printable characters, there is a decryption operation. As you noted, this is only a toy algorithm. My intent was to help him understand why mapping through a printable medium (where non-printables are converted) would result in his observed results.

Comment: @tvanfosson when I enter your solution I get the error: Type mismatch: cannot covert from int to char. How to I go around this?

Comment: @sketchiii - cast the result

Comment: @tvanfosson I'm sorry but I get the exact same result "astu" gives "as33" when I use this solution. I'll edit my question to show how I implemented your solution.